# Java's BigInteger class

Tags: java, math

What algorithms does Java's BigInteger class employ for multiplication and division, and what are their respective time complexities?

What primitive type does Java's BigInteger class use - byte, short, int, etc. - and why?

How does Java's BigInteger class handle the fact that its primitive type is signed? If the answer is it just does it and it's really messy, that's all I need/want to know. What I'm really getting at is does it cheat in the same way some python libraries cheat in that they're not written in python?

Comment: If you dig around the source is online somewhere -- you can check it out for yourself.

Comment: It uses schoolbook multiplication and division implemented in Java.  It's...not fast.

Comment: Depends on the vendor, IBM has some own stuff. It generally uses byte[] arrays. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigInteger.java#1181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle's java.math.BigInteger class has undergone some extensive improvements from Java 7 to Java 8. See for yourself by examining the source on [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=BigInteger). It doesn't cheat, it's all pure java.

Internally, it uses a [sign-magnitude representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) of the integer, using an array of `int` values to store the magnitude. Recall that a java int is a 32-bit value. All 32-bits are used without regard to the sign. This size is also convenient since the product of two `int`s fits into a java `long`.

Beginning in Java 8 the BigInteger class added some advanced algorithms such as Karatsuba and Toom-Cook multiplication to improve the performance for integers of thousands of bits.

Comment: "used without regard to the sign" - How? By using bit-wise operators instead of arithmetic operators?

Comment: The operands are converted to long before arithmetic is per performed. You should examine the code to learn more, for example the [add](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/math/BigInteger.java#BigInteger.add%28int%5B%5D%2Cint%5B%5D%29) method.

Comment: Thanks ... in retrospect that should have been easily deducible from your answer.

Comment: "The operands are converted to long before arithmetic is per performed." and "This size is also convenient since the product of two ints fits into a java long." The product of two numbers in the range [0, 2^32) doesn't fit into a long.

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn: A java long is 64-bits. The product of two 32-bit integers is an integer whose magnitude is < 2*64, therefore it fits in a long.

Comment: Longs are in the range [-2^63, 2^63). Maybe I'm using a different definition of magnitude. I brought up "The operands are converted to long before arithmetic is per performed." in the context of "used without regard to the sign" which together I took to mean, the number gets shifted into the positive range after it's cast to long.

Comment: If the BigInteger class uses a sign-magnitude representation and all 32 bits of each integer are used then 1 and -1 correspond to unique positive numbers and yet, if not shifted, their product with themselves yields the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at the source code to `BigInteger` [here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html). Here's what I found.

`BigInteger` does not "cheat". In Java "cheating" is accomplished through the use of what are known as "native" functions. See `java.lang.Math` for a rather extensive list of these.

`BigInteger` uses `int` to represent its data.

```
private transient int[] words;
```

And yes, it is pretty messy. Lot's of bit crunching at the like.

Answer (score 0):

[It uses `int`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html).

Reason: It's the fastest for most platforms.

Comment: If two ints are faster than a long why do longs exist?

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn A long is essentially just two ints (double the size in bits). Of course a single variable is faster than two variables. 32 bits is the natural size for many PC architectures, that's why Java uses that size for it's ints.

Comment: When I said "why do longs exist" I meant "why do processors have built in support for longs". Are you saying I'm wrong about that, and ints are the biggest integral types with native support?

Comment: Longs exist to allow representation of 64-bit wide integers with a single variable. Most systems have good native support for them, and it's a good feature, there are many cases when 32 bits just aren't enough.

Comment: You misunderstand. If it's more time efficient to represent a 64 bit BigInt as two ints instead of one long, why do most processors have built in support for longs - it would be faster to implement them in software.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. The hardware-level optimizations make it already really fast.

Comment: But yeah I'm no expert on this matter. Although I believe they would implement it in the most effective way, so using long instead of two ints is probably faster because of the optimized hardware. And an array of ints is probably faster too, because of the hw optimizations as well. But in reality it can of course be a little slower on some machine, and faster on another, it depends. The way they have implemented it probably just reflects what's most efficient in most systems.